# VB Script: create shortcut to open file with specific program (mspaint)

Tags: vbscript

I am using VB script to create a shortcut file to open an image. No problems there. Where I am having problems is: trying to open that image with mspaint.exe specifically; I cannot get the `oLink.TargetPath` to save into the shortcut's "target" field in its properties. I get an error message that says it expects end of statement at `"C:\_`. Please help! :)

```
Set shc = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
templateFile = "Mockup_myTest_Shortcut.lnk" 
Set oLink = shc.CreateShortcut(templateFile)
oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe" "C:\_ OneDrive\Corporativo Bimbo, S.A. de C. 
V\Barcel USA Information Technology - Documents\_ Wrike\Specification Mockups\_ Mockup Template.png"
oLink.Save
```

[image: File Explorer]

Comment: I think you need to use `oLink.Arguments` instead of trying to stick the arguments in the `TargetPath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I think you need to use `oLink.Arguments`

Basically:

```
oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe"
oLink.Arguments = "C:\_ OneDrive\Corporativo Bimbo, S.A. de C. V\Barcel USA Information Technology - Documents\_ Wrike\Specification Mockups\_ Mockup Template.png"
```

Comment: Thank you! One minor change: """C:\_ OneDrive\Corporativo Bimbo, S.A. de C. V\Barcel USA Information Technology - Documents\_ Wrike\Specification Mockups\_ Mockup Template.png"""